# Making table that displays overlaying shapefile information?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, layers, fields-attributes

I have a parcel I'm working with that has multiple layers laid over it. I'd like to make a table that displays various attributes of those different layers. For example, within that shapefile, I'd like to have a table display the watershed, school district, utilities, etc. and if that parcel changes, I'd like the table information to change too. I've experimented with data driven pages, but I'm not sure that's quite what I'm looking for.

Any suggestions?

Comment: how about uploading that shape file in postgis and there manipulate it in the way you want with SQL queries?

Comment: Have a look at the Spatial Join tool, this will join the attributes of a layer to another based upon your chosen relationship (e.g. Intersects). This is a one time join so not something that updates if you pan around.

Comment: @Hornbydd I think you should turn your comment into a brief answer.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Hornbydd:

> Have a look at the Spatial Join tool, this will join the attributes of
>   a layer to another based upon your chosen relationship (e.g.
>   Intersects). This is a one time join so not something that updates if
>   you pan around.